# Get next element with the same class

Tags: jquery

I use a click event for an element with certain class. Inside the click event function I need to get the next element on page with the same class. I tried:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var $next = $(this).next('.class')  
});
```

And:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var $next = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.class')  
});
```

The .class is a div inside td in a table, that's why three times parent().

My HTML is something like this (The .class is .drag):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="black8">
<tr class="trow1 drop trow1_over" 
    rel="0,1">
    <td>
            <div class="drop rootFolder" 
                 rel="0,1"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="100%" 
        class="folderListOnclick">

            <span>.. (koreňový adresár)</span>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr><tr class="trow1">
    <td>
        <div class="drag drop ordinaryFolder" 
             rel="1,1" 
             style="width: 40px;">

        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="100%" 
        class="folderListOnclick" 
        rel="1">
            <span>aaa</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="button_mini folderEditOnclick" 
             rel="1">
                    <span></span>

        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="button_mini folderDeleteOnclick" 
             rel="1">
                    <span><span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr><tr class="trow1">
    <td>

        <div class="drag drop ordinaryFolder" 
             rel="19,1" 
             style="width: 50px;">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="100%" 
        class="folderListOnclick" 
        rel="19">
            <span>subaaa</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="button_mini folderEditOnclick" 
             rel="19">

                    <span></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="button_mini folderDeleteOnclick" 
             rel="19">
                    <span><span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Comment: Why isn't your approach working?

Comment: @Luca: Because `next()` does not work this way. It only returns the *next sibling* **iff** it matches the given selector.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I posted HTML example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(".drag").click(function() {
    var draggables = $(this).parents("table").find(".drag");
    var $next = draggables.filter(":gt(" + draggables.index(this) + ")").first();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Slightly cleaner version of this line: `var $next = draggables.eq(draggables.index(this));`

Answer (score 5):

How about this? You should check for off-by-one errors though, because I haven't tested it.

```
$('.class').click(function () {
  var index = $('.class').index($(this));
  var $next = $('.class').slice(index+1,index+2);
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), and [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var elements = $('.class');

elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var $next = elements.slice(index+1, index+2);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pKxYz/1/)

Alternatively (though maybe less efficient) would be to get a reference to the common ancestor and use `slice()` and `index()`:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var elements = $(this).closest('table').find('.class');
    var index = elements.index(this);
    $next = elements.slice(index + 1, index + 2);
});
```

Comment: @Richard: Define *doesn't work*. The demo works as it should I think.

Comment: @Richard Knop: Maybe you used the code before I updated `i` to `index`. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's been a lot of time from this question, but... I find another way to do this in one line:

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){
    const next = $(this).nextAll('.class').eq(0)
    ...
})
```

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.class').removeClass('next')
    $(this).nextAll('.class').eq(0).addClass('next')
})
```

```css
a {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 16px;
  width: 200px;
}
a.next {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="class">Class 1</a>
<a href="#" class="noclass">Noclass 1</a>
<a href="#" class="class">Class 2</a>
<a href="#" class="noclass">Noclass 2</a>
<a href="#" class="noclass">Noclass 3</a>
<a href="#" class="class">Class 3</a>
```