# Getting the next element of the same type

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have some structure like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <input .../>
  </li>
  <li>
      This item doesn't have an input
  </li>
  <li>
      <input .../>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input .../>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Given a reference to one of the `input` elements, how can I get the next or previous `input` in the list?

---

Edit: some `<li>` elements don't have an input; I need the code to handle those cases.

Comment: How do you want to handle the beginning/end? wrap around or find nothing?

Comment: @tvanfosson wrapping would be nice, but it's not terribly important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265151/62024):

```
var inputs = $("input");
var currentIndex = inputs.index(this);
var next = inputs.filter(function (index) { return index == currentIndex + 1; })
```

Comment: Mod `currentIndex + 1` by the length of `inputs` and you get the wrap around effect.

Answer (score 8):

If `this` is the current input:

```
$(this).closest('li').next('li').find('input');
```

Comment: That works. Is there a way that relies less on the actual structure of the document? For example, I'd like to be able to change the `ul` into some other structure (a table, articles, whatever). Also, some `li` don't have an input; I need to handle that.